# ¿alguna forma de leer comentarios de preguntas borradas?

Tags: discusión, comentarios, eliminación-de-preguntas

Hoy me encontré en mi bandeja de comentarios con lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo, la pregunta [fue quitada por su autor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/334371/imagen-repetida-el-todo-el-flexbox?noredirect=1#comment607181_334371).
Revisé en la página de mi perfil, sección de respuestas y tampoco pude encontrar el comentario. 
Yo asumo que debe estar en alguna parte si aún se muestra parte de la respuesta en la bandeja.
La verdad es que estoy curioso a que se refería el comentario, no recuerdo que pude haber escrito para obtener una respuesta que comience así (y si, al parecer encontraron detalles en mi código perfecto que nadie más que yo puede hacer, a quien no le han tocado el ego ahí ).
Tengo casi asumido que la respuesta es NO, no se puede leer comentarios de preguntas borradas, pero nada se pierde con preguntar.

Comment: El comentario como tal aún existe pues lo que se eliminó fue la pregunta, bajo esa idea es visible para aquellos usuarios con una reputación >= 10000

Comment: Ahora por lo que leo no hay nada de *malo* o *que se pueda mal interpretar*, pues tu dejaste 2 preguntas referidas a 2 términos que uso la persona que escribió y por lo que se lee esta persona te los esta explicando; es decir te estaba aclarando a que se refería

Comment: Por satisfacer tu curiosidad, lo único que hacía el op era definirte [_cutre_](https://dle.rae.es/cutre)

Comment: @Pikoh jajajajajja, ok, gracias

Comment: El problema es que al recibir la bandeja de entrada por correo electrónico también aparece incompleto.

Answer (score 2):

Obtén el privilegio [Acceso a herramientas de moderación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) para lo cual sólo se requieren 10k de reputación o bien espera a ser electo como moderador diamantado.

Comment: De todos modos es raro que la notificación no se _limpiara_ de la bandeja del usuario tras tantas horas

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Me parece que no tenemos suficiente información (al menos no está en la pregunta). ¿Sabes en que momento se eliminó la pregunta y cuando el OP cargó la página?

Comment: A mí me siguen apareciendo las notificaciones de quién me responde aún cuando hayan pasado horas luego de eliminar la pregunta o respuesta

Comment: Se borró a las 8.04 y lo reportó a las 17 y pico (info sacada de la línea de tiempo)

Comment: @Aprendiz tu tienes el privilegio referido en mi respuesta así que puedes acceder a los comentarios de las preguntas eliminadas. Un usuario que no puede acceder al comentario porque la pregunta/respuesta han sido eliminados "no debería" tener la notificación en su bandeja. No sé si el que pueda accederlo sea por diseño (aunque sea un mal diseño), un bug   conocido o nuevo.

Comment: Lo comento por qué a veces me aparecen notificaciones y en otras ocasiones no aunque me arroben

Comment: @Aprendiz ¿Aún no hay una pregunta al respecto?

Comment: A mí me constaba la lógica descrita aquí: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231990/209901  por lo que pensé que la notificación se eliminaría de oa bandeja del usuario si no puede acceder a ella

Comment: Gracias por el link @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' (cabe destacar que ese hilo es de hace 6 años). Me parece que esto debería tratarse en otro lado y no aquí (esta respuesta es para responder una pregunta, aunque relacionada, sobre otra cosa)